# Issues with Selection and Viewing of Attribute Table using QGIS and SQL Server Express 2008 R2

Tags: qgis, sql-server-spatial

I am having issues with Selection using QGIS 2.0.1. Dufour. When I select one point, all of the points get highlighted. Attribute Table dialog shows Errors for all of the attributes. It indicates that Features total:12691, filtered:12691, selected: 1. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in QGIS 2.0.1 when it comes to SQL Server [uniqueidentifier] data type. QGIS 2.0.1 does not know how to handle a column that is defined to be [uniqueidentifier]. It exhibits the behavior described in my question. In my case I had [GlobalId] [uniqueidentifier] which was the primary key as well. Once I removed the [uniqueidentifier] then all was normal.

Answer (score -1):

Your table does not have a primary key.

QGIS must detect a primary key to work.

Make a primary key field in your table and everything should go OK.