# QGIS 2.14.10 MS SQL Server 2008 Primary Key Issue

Tags: qgis-2, sql-server-spatial

I've just spent the last hour wrestling with a spatial selection problem on an MS SQL Server layer in QGIS 2.14.10. The layer is a point layer and each time I click on a point every point in the layer is selected. It sounded similar to the problem described here:

[issues with selection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76354/issues-with-selection-and-viewing-of-attribute-table-using-qgis-and-sql-server-e)

However, I had no uniqueidentifier data type in my table. What I did have was a VarChar(16) clustered primary key called TaxOcc. Once I removed this key and added an integer clustered primary key called id my spatial table started behaving as expected in QGIS. If I click on a single point using the select tool, only that single point is selected :-). Is this a bug or a feature? Do primary keys in MSSQL Server need to be integers and called id in order for the table to work properly in QGIS? Anyway whichever, hope the above saves someone else some time :-)

Ian